# Xamarin.iOS not compatible on Mac myMac.local

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am getting the following error ! and i have upto date xamarin Visual studio.

```
The installed xamarin.ios(version 10.4)on mac myMac.local.(172.26.17.*) is not compatible with the local Xamarin.ios(version).
```

Can any one help me out here. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Make sure that your Xamarin.iOS Versions are both on the same major version. i.e. Ensure you are on the Stable channel on both your Mac and Windows machines. Please ensure you are using Xamarin Studio on Mac and Visual Studio on Windows as they are both considered stable. Visual Studio for Mac is still in Preview.

Comment: @JonDouglas i`m using Windows machine, and MAC machine for only iPhone app testing, My question is i need to update Xamarin studio for Mac Machine

Comment: Yes, if you are pairing your Windows machine to the Mac machine, they both need to be on the same major version.

Comment: Follow Jon advice, both Xamarin version MUST match the one on your VS side and the one installed on your Mac

Comment: @JonDouglas  Thank you !! working now

Comment: @SergioAMG  Thank you !! working now

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Xamarin.iOS Versions are both on the same major version. i.e. Ensure you are on the Stable channel on both your Mac and Windows machines. Please ensure you are using Xamarin Studio on Mac and Visual Studio on Windows as they are both considered stable. Visual Studio for Mac is still in Preview.